# Putting an image inside an combobox (right-hand edge) in Delphi/Win32

Tags: delphi, winapi, combobox, delphi-7

I want draw a an image inside an combobox (right-hand edge) in Delphi/Win32.

The combobox has the style **csDropDown**. This doesn't work with *csOwnerDrawFixed* or *csOwnerDrawVariable*.

The combobox should be editable similar to the address bar of the browser.

Is there a Win32 solution without creating an additional Delphi component?

I tried the following, but it doesn't work. Can I do that with Delphi 7?

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  ...
private
  FChDirComboWndProc: TWndMethod;
  procedure ChDirComboWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
  ...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FChDirComboWndProc := ChDirComboBox.WindowProc; // save old window proc
  ChDirComboBox.WindowProc := ChDirComboWndProc; // subclass
end;

procedure TForm1.ChDirComboWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
    WM_ERASEBKGND: begin    // WM_PAINT ?
        SetBkMode(Message.WParam, TRANSPARENT);
        SetTextColor(Message.wParam, GetSysColor(COLOR_GRAYTEXT));
        FillRect(Message.wParam, Rect(3,3,300,30), GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH ));
        Rectangle(Message.wParam, 15,15, 100, 100); //Test
        OutputDebugString(PCHar(Format('aa %d %d %d',[Message.WParam, Message.LParam, ChDirComboBox.Handle])));
      end;
  end;
  FChDirComboWndProc(Message); // process message
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

The way to do it is to implement an `Owner-Drawn Combo Boxes`. See [Owner-Drawn Combo Boxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775791%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#owner_drawn) on MSDN, or look for Delphi sample, e.g. [Owner Draw - ComboBox](http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicssnippets/ownerdraw-combobox).

Comment: The combobox has the style **csDropDown**. This doesn't work with csOwnerDrawFixed or csOwnerDrawVariable. The combobox should be editable similar to the address bar of the browser. I'll add this information to my question, sorry to forget that.